# DOTS entity debugger -- trouble inspecting elements within a dynamic buffer

Tags: unity, gui, unity-dots

I'm using Unity 2021.2.7f1 with the latest versions of DOTS available.

[image: screencap]

When I open up the entities debugger "Windows / DOTS / Enities" I can begin inspecting the live component values associated with a chosen entity. However for dynamic buffers each element's data is locked behind a greyed-out Foldout... I can't unfold the UI, and so I'm unable to inspect live data in each element.

I can however see the element values during **edit time** via the Preview window of the inspector GUI.

[image]

Does anybody have a solution or workaround to inspect live runtime dynamicBuffer data? Is the entity debugger extendable like inspector GUIs are?

Comment: I suspect that this is just one of the many small issues and limitations you can expect when using a preview package. So the answer is likely "not possible now, but perhaps possible in a future version of the entity debugger".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Philipp commented, looks like this is a known issue with the entity debugger and a bunch of other Unity editors in the 2021.2 beta. From discussions on the Unity Forum it seems to have something to do with upgrading UI Toolkit versions with breaking changes that resulted in some regressions, including in the entity debugger.